# Хочу понять, как настроить Gateaway, чтоб он получал картинки из media:/recipes (Это volumes)

Tags: python, django, nginx, docker, docker-compose

На данный момент настройки такие:

**nginx.conf**

```
location /media/ {
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
alias /media/;
client_max_body_size 20M;
}
```

**docker.compose**

```
volumes:
  foodgram_data_production:
  static:
  media:

services:
   db:
     image: postgres:13.10
     env_file: .env
     volumes:
       - foodgram_data_production:/var/lib/postgresql/data
   backend:
     image: ridleq/foodgram_backend
     env_file: .env
     volumes:
       - static:/backend_static
       - media:/app/media
   frontend:
     image: ridleq/foodgram_frontend
     env_file: .env
     command: cp -r /app/build/. /frontend_static/
   volumes:
     - static:/frontend_static
   gateway:
     image: ridleq/foodgram_infra
     env_file: .env
     volumes:
       - static:/staticfiles/
       - media:/recipes
     ports:
       - 8000:80
```

Сейчас при открытии сайта картинки не грузятся, выдает ошибку:`project-react-gateway-1   | 2023/12/13 19:37:21 [error] 40#40: *24 open() "/staticfiles/media/recipes/photo_RJHdeEe.png" failed (2: No such file or directory)`